# RTC calibration in energy meter IC 71M6541F

Tags: embedded, energy

How do I calibrate the [RTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) of energy meter IC 71M6541F?

Here are the details:

I am working on the above mentioned [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip) on smart meter project. Using 32.768 kHz frequency I am getting an accurate time without any mismatch with global time. But in the crystal there is a small deviation so that I am undergoing 2 to 4 second difference in real time in 24 hours of time. How do I rectify this problem?

Comment: This question is kind of off-topic, as you are asking about the behavior about a specific IC, rather than about a programming problem. Such questions are more suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or since it is such a niche question, it is best to ask Maxim tech support directly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking about the physical properties of a hardware device (crystal).

Comment: @Lundin: That is not about the IC, but crystals and their tolerances in general. OP might ask how to add/subtract a value from an integer.

Comment: Use an atomic clock. But that still has some deviation. You should learn about the properties of physical devices you use and their implications.

Comment: @Olaf According to the datasheet, this particular device comes with numerous intricate on-chip calibrations. There's lots of things that could cause the clock to drift, for example incorrect temperature compensation.

Comment: @Lundin: Just had a short peek. You are right. So OP should read the DS and any application note, if available. Now it looks more like a "please do my job" question.

Comment: Energy meter for what? If it is mains you most likely have a very stable long-term clock source in the mains frequency, 50 Hz. I think in most places the utility companies are required to provide a long-term very high accuracy in the frequency (although the short-term accuracy can be off by on the order of 10 seconds (as accumulated error)).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that affordable crystals have always a deviation. Typical values are 30 ppm.

And as each crystal has its own deviation you need to calibrate each system or you need an external sync mechanism.